# mysql select query on multiple table name string

Tags: mysql

I want to do the below query in mysql. How can I do it in a single select query in mysql? I want to run the same count statement in a list of tables. Inner query returns the dynamic table name strings.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM ( list of table names from a select statemt)   Where Col1 is NULL;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT CONCAT('TABLE',id) TABLENAMES FROM CUSTOMTABLE WHERE Active=1)  AA  WHERE AA.COL1 IS NULL;
```

Could anyone help me out regarding this?

Comment: Are you against doing SELECT COUNT (\*) FROM TABLE1 UNION SELECT COUNT (\*) FROM TABLE2 UNION SELECT COUNT (\*) FROM TABLE 3...?

Comment: How would you expect the result to look? two counts in the same row, or 1 count on two rows?

Comment: Just 1 complete count of all the tables.  I dont want individual table count. Thx.  Since I want the sum count of all tables  cant apply union here.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a combination of two things:

1. The set `union` operator, and
2. A subquery that returns the result on the intermediate operation that involves the union.

Consider you have an `account` table and an `employee` table.

```
mysql> desc account;
+--------------------+----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| account_id         | int(10) unsigned                 | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_cd         | varchar(10)                      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| cust_id            | int(10) unsigned                 | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| open_date          | date                             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| close_date         | date                             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_activity_date | date                             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status             | enum('ACTIVE','CLOSED','FROZEN') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| open_branch_id     | smallint(5) unsigned             | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| open_emp_id        | smallint(5) unsigned             | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| avail_balance      | float(10,2)                      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pending_balance    | float(10,2)                      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc employee;
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| emp_id             | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fname              | varchar(20)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lname              | varchar(20)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| start_date         | date                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| end_date           | date                 | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| superior_emp_id    | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dept_id            | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| title              | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| assigned_branch_id | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, you want to count the total number of rows in both the tables satisfying certain conditions. So, you use union first:

`select account_id id from account union all select emp_id id from employee`

This gives you a table that represents a `union` of these two tables account and employee and you make sure that they have the same 'data' that agrees with union operation. The above query is the simplest, it just selects emp_id from employee table and account_id from account table and renames the columns to id. This makes the data 'union-friendly'. Of course, you can apply your filter conditions here. The `all` operator selects all the records even if there are duplicates (Remember from set theory, a set contains all unique members).

Now, the first part, the subquery:

```
mysql> select count(*) from 
       (select account_id id from account union all 
        select emp_id id from employee) u;
```

and that returns:

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       42 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and that can be verified:

```
mysql> select count(*) from employee;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       18 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from account;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       24 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thx for the info .  Inner query is a dynamic table name     select `tablename` from account   and not  'select account_id id from account union all 
        select emp_id id from employee'

Comment: Well, I have run all these queries against some real data and added the results here. Are you saying it does not answer your question, or are you saying that these queries are incorrect? (And by inner query, do you mean subquery?)

Comment: Apologies subquery  ( select account_id id from account union all 
        select emp_id id from employee)  here it returns accountid  but in my case it need to return the real table name that will be queried in the outerquery based on subquery results.   so it will be ( select concat('table' ,id)  as tablename from testtab where active=1)